# Sending bulk HTTP in java

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bulk, executors

the program is used to read a file, and send each line as http.
every line in the file is a url.

e.g. http: //localhost:8080/?a=1&b=2

```
    PoolingClientConnectionManager pcm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
    pcm.setMaxTotal(200);
    pcm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(pcm);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    try (BufferedReader bfrDataSource = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        while((line=bfrDataSource.readLine()) != null){
            executorService.execute(new SendTask(line, client));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

SendTask.java

```
public class SendTask implements Runnable {

private String url;
private final HttpClient client;

public SendTask(String url, HttpClient client){
    this.url = url;
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        httpGet.abort();
    }
}
```

}

when i send the file with 500,000 lines, it works.
but then it send 100,000 lines, one error has occurred:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

- how to modify the program to make sure it can send at least 1 million lines? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The thread pool created by Executors.newFixedThreadPool() is backed by an unbounded queue, when you submit new tasks to it and there is no available work threads, it will cache the task in the queue. That's why you get OOM exception.

To fix it, you need to use a thread pool with a bounded work queue:

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

There are various queue implementation can be used, but in your case, SynchronousQueue should be enough.

Besides, you should shutdown the httpclient after you worker finish its job:

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Check [httpclient javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) for details.

Comment: It's even possible to share the httpClient between multiple threads.

Comment: based on your answers, the question has update, please have a look.

Comment: @jychan Could you provide the exact url when the exception is raised? You might need to add some log to print out the erroneous url.

Comment: @ericson but if i send the url as a single thread, not using executors, it all will be send out normally.

Comment: @jychan at least you can tell whether the target url is hosted on the same machine which your program runs, or is it a remote site? If it is a remote site, the server might block your request as you are sending too many concurrent requests at high rate.

Comment: @jychan Have you changed the ExecutorService implementation as I mentioned in the answer? It looks like you are still using _Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)_ in your updated code.